# Can someone please tell me what this Puppet statement means and different syntaxes for achieving the same result?

Tags: arrays, syntax, byte, puppet

I ran into this Puppet statement but I'm not really sure what it means (I don't write much Puppet at all):

```
[byte[]](0x00,0xFF,0xFF,0x00)
```

Does anyone recognise the syntax of this statement and what it's doing? It almost looks like some kind of implicit cast or shorthand byte array population?

The actual statement I found is much longer and on a single line.

1. I'd like to understand what it means, I'm assuming its some kind of array of byte arrays?
2. If possible I'd like a different way of expressing it across multiple lines, the current expression is making my Puppet linter angry as the line is over 140 characters. Yes, I know the linter is configurable, but this is a nice opportunity to learn something new.

I've tried searching Google and the Puppet docs for examples with similar syntax, but the closest I've found is something like this:

```
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("mystring");
```

Which is creating a byte array from the string data.

Comment: It would appear to be a custom data type constructor invocation, but without the necessary context it would be difficult to be certain.

Comment: This is not valid puppet.  It looks like a line of c# initialising a byte array https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding?view=net-7.0

Comment: That is not a complete statement, nor even a complete expression.  It might be *part of* an invocation of a constructor for some data type, but if so then the actual data type name is missing, and `byte` would have to be a custom data type (it is not among the built-in ones).  If you want us to tell you what it means, then we need to see more context.

Comment: And the `Encoding.UTF8` thing is not Puppet at all.